# 2nd ODE Question Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{d^2u}{dy^2} + \frac{V}{\rho} \frac{du}{dy} = 0
$$
conditions $u = 0$ at $y = 1$ and $u = U_0$ at $y= 0$

$V,\rho$ are constants

find solution for $u(y)$

My final answer was

$$u(y)=\frac{U_0}{1-\exp(-V/\rho)}-\frac{U_0}{(1-\exp(V/\rho))\exp(V/\rho)}$$

would anyone be able to clarify if i did this correctly please

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use MathJax for to write your problem.

Comment: The exponential at the denominator dosent seem right. Can you post your full answer so we can check where the mistakes are ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2u}{dy^2} + \frac{V}{\rho} \frac{du}{dy} = 0$$
$$\frac{du}{dy} + \frac{V}{\rho}u = C_1$$
$$(ue^{yV/{ \rho}})'=C_1e^{yV/{\rho}}$$
$$ue^{yV/{ \rho}}=Ce^{yV/{\rho}}+C_2$$
$$u(y)=C+C_2e^{-yV/{ \rho}}$$
Apply initial conditions. I think that you can simplify a little bit your answer with the exponential.